How to access more storage?
I am doing a project with an STM32 chip. It needs to access megabytes of storage, but the chip can only access up to 32 Kilobytes of Flash memory.
Is there a way to add more memory?

There most certainly is. However the question is so vague to answer any better. Improve the question to be more specific than "yes".

What is the STM32 part you are using?

Yes, there are external flash chips. They usually communicate by quad or octo SPI.
Example: W25Q128JVSIQ

There are also memory cards that are gigabytes in size, accessed just as easily or even easier.
